# Why is my drop down menu acting strangely?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

So I'm creating a rails application with a nav bar at the top of the page. However, when I implement the following code and click on "Categories" the names do not get displayed. Im also attaching a picture.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle= "dropdown" role="button"
      aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:category] == category.name%>">
          <%= link_to category.name, attractions_path(category: category.name), class: "link"%>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

[image: menu does not drop down.picture]

Now, when I change my code to the following, I can see the items that should be displayed in the drop down menu. What am I doing wrong? why is it behaving like this?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle= "dropdown" role="button"
      aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-toggle" role="menu">
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:category] == category.name%>">
          <%= link_to category.name, attractions_path(category: category.name), class: "link"%>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

[image: links are there.picture]

So basically Im just changing this line `<ul class="dropdown-toggle" role="menu">`.

Why is my menu not dropping down displaying all my categories?

Comment: You're using Bootstrap for the navbar, right?

Comment: And the only difference is `<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">` in the first/not-working one but `<ul class="dropdown-toggle" role="menu">` in the second/working one, right?

Comment: Correct, Im using boostrap. The second one is kind of working. What it does, it just displays the items that should be in the dropdown but they are always displayed like if they were just html links. So when I click on it, it doesnt do anything.

Comment: Bootstrap version 3 or 4?

Comment: Im using Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use a Bootstrap3 navbar set up with Bootstrap4. There have been some changes but you should be able to rebuild it based on the [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content) in the documentation:

- The items in your `nav` should be marked with `nav-item` classes.
- You don't need to add the caret (`<span class="caret">`) yourself anymore.
- The items in your drop down need to be marked with `dropdown-item` classes now.
- The dropdown toggle should look like:

  ```
  <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="someId">
  ```

  rather than:

  ```
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle= "dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
  ```
- The dropdown menu should be linked back to its toggle with `aria-labelledby="someId"`.

Putting those together gives you something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="someId">
      Categories
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="someId">
      <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <li class="dropdown-item <%= 'active' if params[:category] == category.name %>">
          <%= link_to category.name, attractions_path(category: category.name), class: "link"%>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

You'd want to use something sensible to replace `someId` of course.

Comment: I just did one of these so it is pretty fresh in my mind, cheers 